# Create background-image cycle with jQuery

Tags: css, image, rotation, background-image

working on a website where the client wants the "background image" of the website to cycle through 3 images.

Now I have created cycles before (or installed plugins) to cycle through img tags... but not made a jQuery function that contacts the css of a div and gives it a new image to "fade" to every 7 seconds...

Does anyone have an idea how to do this???

---

Now I would like to have the images fade through as img tags within a div but unfortunately this cannot be done in this case as the div that has the changing background images is resizable, and has images far wider than it, that need to be positioned in the center of it - hense using the css image-position:center tag...

thanks for the help

---

Comment: Just use multiple containers with the background image set and then cycle through those. Otherwise you arent going to be able to animate unless you use css3 transitions (i think they can handle that but i havent messed with 'em).

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you don't prefer to do this by a div but you can animate just the background color.
Here is my solution of the problem. I've used two images so you've got to add one url more into the array and change `count % 2` to `count % 3` to fit into your case (with three different images for background).
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5uBej/4/

And the source:

**JS**

```
(function ($) {
    var images = ['http://silviahartmann.com/background-tile-art/images/fire_flame/fire_seamless_background_2.jpg', 'http://www.myinkblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/polaroid-background.jpg'],
        count = 0, 
        timeout, interval = 1500;

    $('#foo').width($(document).width()); 
    $('#foo').height($(document).height());   

    (function changeBackground() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#foo').fadeOut(function () {

                if (count === 100) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                $('#foo').css('background-image', 'url(' + images[count % 2] + ')');
                $('#foo').fadeIn();
                count += 1;
                changeBackground();
            });
        }, interval);
    }());
}($));
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://www.myinkblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/polaroid-background.jpg);
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -2147483648;
}
.content {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
h1 {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo" id="foo"></div>

<div class="content">
    <h1>Sample header</h1>
    Sample content here...
</div>
```

I hope that these lines of code helped you :-).

Best regards.